# Tuleap - pre-configured Fields

Tags: tuleap

So I'm new to Tuleap and creating a tracker for development activities, I've included all the fields for effort, Initial Effort, Remaining Effort and percentage of completion.
I was expecting sort of automatic calculation for remaining effort or percentage of completion, but they are just simple fields.
Is it there a way to make a field based on a formula of other fields?
I understand that a computed value only does some calculations based on children artifacts

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a specific "Computed field" for those calculation instead of plain "Integer" or "Float" types.

Then you can either have a manually entered value or a computed value from the linked artifacts.